# unrecognized selector sent to instance while trying to add an object to a mutable array

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I'm following the "[Your Second iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html)" and I decided to play with the code to understand Objective C well...

What I'm trying to do is simply adding an object to a mutable array in a class. Here are the classes:

**BirdSighting.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BirdSighting : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *location;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDate *date;

-(id) initWithName: (NSString *) name location:(NSString *) location date:(NSDate *) date;
@end
```

**BirdSighting.m**

```
#import "BirdSighting.h"

@implementation BirdSighting
-(id) initWithName:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location date:(NSDate *)date
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        _name = name;
        _location = location;
        _date = date;

        return self;
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

**BirdSightingDataController.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class BirdSighting;

@interface BirdSightingDataController : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *masterBirdSightingList;

- (NSUInteger) countOfList;
- (BirdSighting *) objectInListAtIndex: (NSUInteger) theIndex;
- (void) addBirdSightingWithSighting: (BirdSighting *) sighting;
@end
```

**BirdSightingDataController.m**

```
#import "BirdSightingDataController.h"

@implementation BirdSightingDataController
- (id) init {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        NSMutableArray *sightingList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.masterBirdSightingList = sightingList;
        return self;
    }

    return nil;
}

-(NSUInteger) countOfList 
{
    return [self.masterBirdSightingList count];
}

- (BirdSighting *) objectInListAtIndex: (NSUInteger) theIndex
{
    return [self.masterBirdSightingList objectAtIndex:theIndex];
}

- (void) addBirdSightingWithSighting: (BirdSighting *) sighting
{
    [self.masterBirdSightingList addObject:sighting];
}
@end
```

And this is where I'm trying to add a BirdSighting instance to the mutable array:

```
#import "BirdsMasterViewController.h"
#import "BirdsDetailViewController.h"

#import "BirdSightingDataController.h"
#import "BirdSighting.h"

@implementation BirdsMasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    BirdSightingDataController *dataController = [[BirdSightingDataController alloc] init];

    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    BirdSighting *sighting = [[[BirdSighting alloc] init] initWithName:@"Ebabil" location:@"Ankara" date: date];

    [dataController addBirdSightingWithSighting: sighting];
    NSLog(@"dataController: %@", dataController.masterBirdSightingList);

    self.dataController = dataController;

}
..........
@end
```

It throws NSInvalidArgumentException in BirdSightingDataController addBirdSightingWithSighting method...

What am I doing wrong?

This is the full debug output:
2012-11-26 01:22:38.495 BirdWatching[4597:c07] -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71899d0
2012-11-26 01:22:38.496 BirdWatching[4597:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71899d0'

Comment: What's the rest of the error? The log should provide more details about the invalid argument exception. I'm guessing you are trying to add a `nil` reference to the array.

Comment: Well I checked it with the debugger, it's not nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
BirdSighting *sighting = [[[BirdSighting alloc] init] initWithName:@"Ebabil" location:@"Ankara" date: date];
```

should be:

```
BirdSighting *sighting = [[BirdSighting alloc] initWithName:@"Ebabil" location:@"Ankara" date: date];
```

You can't call two initializers.

Update:

Based on the complete error message I now see the problem. The `NSMutableArray` you think you have for the property is really an `NSArray`. This is caused by defining the property with `copy`.

When you define `copy` for a property, it makes an immutable copy of the object. So when you assign your `NSMutableArray`, an immutable copy is made and then assigned to the instance variable. So you end up assigning an `NSArray`, not an `NSMutableArray`.

A fix is to change the property definition from:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *masterBirdSightingList;
```

to:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *masterBirdSightingList;
```

Comment: I knew I'm missing smt. stupid :) However I'm still getting the same error after fixing it as you described.

Comment: @HotLicks I just updated my answer based on the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error message it says that "addObject" was "sent" to NSArray, and that was invalid.  Which is true.  If you look at the spec for NSArray you will not find a method "addObject".

Somewhere you have an NSArray that you're trying to perform "addObject" on.  Kind of hard to tell where, since you apparently didn't list the section of code where the error occurs, or else you're somewhere setting "masterBirdSightingList" to an NSArray, after first making it an NSMutableArray.

Comment: Ah, as maddy points out, you made the property "copy", which causes strange behavior.

Comment: Its a shame the semantics of `copy` on a property isn't adjusted to `mutableCopy` if the property's type is clearly mutable.

Comment: Yeah, that one would likely burn me.  Would never have noticed it if you hadn't mentioned it.  (But then I've never found much use for `copy`.)

Comment: I learned this a while ago from first hand experience :) The rare times I use `copy` with a mutable type property, I write my own setter to get `mutableCopy` semantics.